# How to set up a standalone python connection pool as a local service?

Tags: python, connection-pooling

I have an optimization requirement. Here are couples of .py scripts share the same template, e.g.

```
def execute_cmd(...):
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    execute_cmd(...)
    ...
```

Each script may consume one or two db connections.

When it goes to run several scripts, that's OK because of low db connection consumption, but if the count goes up, e.g. more than 200 in parallel at the same time, the db connection consumption is huge and not acceptable.
So is there a solution that to set up a shared standalone db connection pool for the python script, like a kind of service?

Note: Each script is triggered as an independent process by other component, such as Jenkins.

Comment: There are other sites where asking how to optimize code is more appropriate. It would seem this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: if you create service then you will have 200 parallel connection to this service. SO you will move problem from one place to another.

Comment: @furas Yes, you're right, this a question where the service should be placed, and there is no silver bullet to fix this completely as long as the connections requirement is needed. Thank you.

Comment: @itprorh66 Thank you for the kind reminding. I will try it out next time. Thank you all the same.